# When server has multiple interfaces, is it better to connect direct to cable modem?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

Currently, my cable modem feeds a single interface on my Proliant which, incidentally, has 4 network interfaces.

I'm running Ubuntu as a LAMP server and I'm wondering if I shouldn't just connect the cable modem directly to the server, configure the NIC for that connection, and then put the AirPort Extreme in Bridge mode without DHCP enabled.

Currently the router sits between the cable-modem and the server and I wonder if I shouldn't just turn the router into a wireless access point, turn off DHCP on it and run DHCP on the server.

Which is the better solution? (P.S., I'm new to linux...)

Comment: Voted to close as this is primarily opinion based, and depends on the specifics of your circumstances and connectivity. I put to you that if you are asking the question (as written) its a bad idea because you have not adequately considered the issues - including security. (From a security POV - in the default case - this would not be a best practice)

Comment: *Which is the better solution?*...better by what measure? Asking the question this way is off-topic here, but if you can reword your question, say to ask which solution is better for blocking unwanted traffic, or faster transmission times, then it can be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution, in general, is to leave the router connected as a router. This typically adds both security and ease of maintenance to your network setup (especially from a configuration standpoint).

Regarding DHCP, I would say there is often nothing wrong with disabling it on a router in favor of using a separate server to hand out addresses. That said, if I understand things correctly, your options seem to stem more from your specific hardware choices than anything else -- particularly, other than Apple's AirPort line, most routers allow you to disable DHCP independently of any other options.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  It makes sense to me to keep a router (whichever I choose) between the server and the connection rather than using two interfaces and using the server as the router.  I may look into a different class of router just to get away from the Apple AirPort Extreme and then use a more robust wifi access point, and move DHCP to the server, or another server altogether.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with whatever you choose. =)